# Set deque max_size up to maximal size

Tags: c++, deque

As I understand, deque is a cyclic buffer, and when it runs out of space, it allocates new space (if it cans). Is there a way to limit the deque can grow to?
Or the only way to make sure it doesn't grow over maximum size is to check every time I want to insert data to deque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as with every STL collection, one of the templated parameters is an allocator.

So you can write your own custom allocator that will keep a track of the memory and throw `bad_alloc` if you exceed this limit, even if the memory is available.

Incidentally, a `std::deque` is usually implemented as a collection of "pages" where each page contains a fixed number of elements.

If you want a circular buffer implementation where you can insert or delete "anywhere", `std::deque` would not be the most efficient to use, `std::list` would be (although there are circular collections available in boost you could use).

Comment: A cutsom allocator seems to be the wrong approach to this problem. There's no strict relationship, that I'm aware of, between between the amount of memory requested for the deque and the size of the deque. There's certainly no such relationship between the size and capacity of a vector for instance.

Comment: You are probably referring to the relationship between the deque implementation itself and the allocator and which one chooses the page size, thus you can't guarantee to perfectly tune it, however given the limitation is probably based on the maximum memory allocation you want to allow for this object, your allocator will be able to manage that, albeit, you may find you cannot actually reach the threshold exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`deque` is not a cyclic buffer; it is typically implemented as a linked collection of arrays.  For a cyclic buffer, look at [`circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) in Boost.

Answer (score 1):

As my experience simplest way is encapsulate the deque by a wrapper class and write two member functions wrapping `push_back` and `push_front`

Answer (score 0):

A deque is not a circular buffer. It may be implemented as a circular buffer, but the implementation details are hidden from the user. I suggest you write a wrapper class or convenience functions to do the size checking for you.